# Making custom tab buttons

Tags: android, layout, tabs, tabwidget

How do I get my tab buttons to look like [image]

What would be the simplest way to do this if I have a drawable in that shape too???

Comment: Creating xml layouts for selectors but they dont fit in properly for the native tabs

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Which part of the implementation are you having problems with?

Comment: basically, I've tried using tabspec.setindicator method with the drawable,but that does'nt fit in properly with the layout,I've also tried a custom xml layout in that method too,so I wanted to knw if there was any other way I could change the native look n feel of the tabs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply you can implement tabs to your application like this

in onCreate method

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("First");

TabSpec firstTab = tabHost.newTabSpec("First");  
firstTab.setIndicator("firstTab",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_first)); //drawable 1
firstTab.setContent(R.id.first_content);    //View
tabHost.addTab(firstTab);

TabSpec secondTab = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second");
secondTab.setIndicator("secondTab",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_second)); //drawable 2
secondTab.setContent(R.id.second_content);    //View
tabHost.addTab(secondTab);

TabSpec thirdTab = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third");
thirdTab.setIndicator("thirdTab",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_third)); //drawable 3
thirdTab.setContent(R.id.third_content);    //View
tabHost.addTab(thirdTab);

tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

in xml file

```
<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@android:id/tabhost">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/first_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <TextView android:text="first_tab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/second_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <TextView android:text="second_tab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/third_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <TextView android:text="third_tab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

call your drawable at getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drawableid));

Comment: re-size your drawables.go to android assert studio and generate tab icons using your drawables.here is the link http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html pls don't forget to rate my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Something that you could do in your activity :

```
private TabHost mTabHost ;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
        // We create a webview for one tab for example
        WebView wv = new WebView(this);
        // add url and options on this webview
        setupTab(wv, "My Title");
}
private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag) {
        View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);
        TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {return view;}
        });

        mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
    }
// this is the method for customize tabs
    private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_tabwidget_custom, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
        tv.setText(text);
        return view;
    }
```

In the R.layout.layout_tabwidget_custom :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabsLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_tab_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabsText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="@drawable/selector_tab_text"
        android:textSize="15dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar work like this. Since Android does not help much is customizing tabs, I just make four tabs button and put it at the end of each xml file. All your Activities would be look similar in this way and it would give a view like Tabs.

Comment: Could u give me an example for that?

Comment: I don't think there is any need of example since its very simple. All you have to do is add four buttons at the bottom of each activity's xml and call appropriate action against them.