# Android Ttlestrip Unselected Tab Color

Tags: android

Hi im working on a new update for my app.So the viewpager tab and where the text is located:
asdasd **asd** asdasd so i need to change the text color of the inactive tab.Lets say the selected on is red and the unselected is grey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a custom tab for that purpose. Some guides:

[Custom tabs in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903796/custom-tabs-in-android)

[Making custom tabs buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409550/making-custom-tab-buttons)

[Android custom font for tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294372/android-custom-font-for-tabs)